# Php get specific word in string

Tags: php

I have a url. I want to parse url. I don't want to get last two value. How can I do?

```
$str="first-second-11.1268955-15.542383564";
```

As I wanted

```
$str="first-second";
```

I used this code. But I don't want to get `-` from last value

```
$arr = explode("-", $str);
for ($a = 0; $a < count($arr) - 2; $a++) {                
    $reqPage .= $arr[$a] . "-";       
}
```

Comment: You can use array_pop() to remove last element from array and then you can implode the array using -

Comment: `substr($reqPage, 0, -1)` will remove last character of your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 3rd param of `explode()` called `limit`:

```
$str="first-second-11.1268955-15.542383564";
$arr = explode("-", $str, -2);
$reqPage = implode($arr, "-"); // contains "first-second"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions too.Those are patterns used to match character combinations in strings.:

```
W*((?i)first-second(?-i))\W*
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the fastest way for the string manipulations. Try this.

```
$str="first-second-11.1268955-15.542383564";
preg_match('/^[a-z]*-{1}[a-z]*/i', $str, $matches);
$match = count($matches) > 0 ? $matches[0] : '';

echo $match;
```

Comment: not fastest.  from php.net, `"If you don't need the power of regular expressions, you can choose faster (albeit simpler) alternatives like explode() or str_split()."`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php